# Wagtail - Override internal links in richtexteditor

Tags: django, wagtail

Since I use wagtail headlessly the internal links get messed up due to them using the site-url listed in settings. Instead, I want to be able to override that same URL and point them to my frontend.

This post talks a little bit about it in 2018, but I'm hoping this has changed?
[Wagtail: Is it possible to disable prepending internal link's with the site domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070996/wagtail-is-it-possible-to-disable-prepending-internal-links-with-the-site-doma)

For external links you'd do something like this to override it:

```
class NewWindowExternalLinkHandler(LinkHandler):
    # This specifies to do this override for external links only.
    identifier = 'external'

    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        href = attrs["href"]
        print(attrs)
        # Let's add the target attr, and also rel="noopener" + noreferrer fallback.
        # See https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4078.
        return '<a href="%s" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">' % escape(href)
```

Is it possible to do the same for internal links?

E.g now since I use a multi-site setup my link looks something like:
https://localhost.my-backend-api-domain.com/page/pagename
I want it to look like this:
https://my-frontend-domain.com/page/pagename

Answer (score 0):

Also I was struggling to change the behaviour of the internal page links.
Intuitivly one would think to follow the external-link example and seethe identifier to `external`.

That's however not the case.  After digging further into the source I was able to change the behaviour of the external link like this:

```
from django.utils.html import escape
from wagtail import hooks
from wagtail.rich_text.pages import PageLinkHandler

from wagtail.models import Page

class TargetNewInternalLinkHandler(PageLinkHandler):
    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        try:
            page = cls.get_instance(attrs)
            return '<a href="%s" class="uk-link uk-link-text">' % escape(page.localized.specific.url)
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            return "<a>"


@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_external_link(features):
    features.register_link_type(TargetNewInternalLinkHandler)
```

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question. But does it help you figure out a solution?